# ¿Como hago para que una img se acomode a lado de un input text?

Tags: html, css

es la primera vez que me animo a pedir ayuda en esta plataforma, espero me pueda ayudar alguien.

Tengo ya hecho un inicio de sesión para mi pagina web mi inconveniente es que quiero que una imagen se mantenga a lado del input usuario y contraseña. lo que intente fue meter una imagen dentro del div de cada input pero solo aparece la imagen arriba del input y no al lado.

Este es mi codigo en html:

```
<div class="modal-dialog text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-8 main-section">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div id="imglogo" class="col-12 ">
        <img src="../img/logo.png">
    </div>

    <form id="validaForm" name="validaForm" class="col-12" action="../usuario.php" method="POST" >

        <div id="msj-cont">
            <h6>AUTENTIFICACIÓN PARA ACCESO AL SISTEMA</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="user-group">
            <img id="userLogo" src="../img/userLog.png">
            <input name="usr" id="usr" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Matrícula">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="contraseña-group">
            <img id="userLogo" src="../assets/img/pwdLog.png">
            <input name="pwd" id="pwd" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña">
        </div>
        <button name="ingresar" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Acceso</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y este es lo que tengo en css:

```
/*contenedor del form*/
.modal-content{
  background-color: #ffffff;
    /*opacity: .85;*/
  padding: 0 20px; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #43B4E4;  
}
.form-group input[type=text], input[type=password]{
height: 30px;
font-size: 18px;
/*border: 1px*/
padding-left: 25px; 
}
#userLogo{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día

Por el contenido en `class` considero estas usando **Bootstrap**; prueba lo siguiente:
lo que esta:

```
<div class="form-group" id="user-group">
        <img id="userLogo" src="../img/userLog.png" align="left">
        <input name="usr" id="usr" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Matrícula">
</div>
```

que sea (por ejemplo):

```
<div class="form-group row" id="user-group">
        <img id="userLogo" src="../img/userLog.png" class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input name="usr" id="usr" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Matrícula">
        </div>
</div>
```

lo anterior para cada `img` junto con su `input`. Asumo que el tamañoi de la imagen para que coincida con el `input` ya lo manejas/controlas.

| https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/ ver **"Readonly plain text"**.

Comment: @BetaM disculpa; pero no comprendí bien. "[...] facilita <b>notarás como si funciona</b>, [...]"; gracias por la orientación y aclaración que corresponda a tu comentario.

Comment: disculpen es que me parece sucedio por que no puse el codigo completo

Comment: Muchas gracias por la orientacion si logre que se acomodara como quería  y gracias a todos lo que se tomaron su tiempo y compartieron conmigo sus conocimientos.

Answer (score 0):

en tu css:

```
div {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> puedes hacer lo siguiente  al contenedor padre agregando la propiedad `display: flex` automáticamente se alinean horizontalmente puedes ver la documentación oficial en el siguiente enlace
>
> Solucion con bootstrap :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-2">
  <div class="col">Column</div>
  <div class="col">Column</div>
  <div class="col">Column</div>
  <div class="col">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> este ejemplo es para 2 columnas 
>   [image: Cita en bloque]
>   [Bootstrap documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#row-columns)